# We didn't find the deployment keyword in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml file

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have a simple pipeline config:

image: python:3.7.3

```
pipelines:

  branches:
    Server:
    - step:
       name: Test
       script:
           - pytest --ignore .
```

which yields the following error:

```
We didn't find the deployment keyword in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml file
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out, that i did not have "bitbucket-pipelines" enabled in the repository in the settings.

Comment: Great, hope it could help you. But i'm sure this answer it's not related to question.

Comment: My posts were deleted somehow. You should use arguments in your answers. I switched on bitbucket-pipelines in the settings and then it worked. So, if you think, that this is not a cause-relationship-effect, you should state an argument for your thesis.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't know happening. But i've edit my answer. 
And i'm sure your question was talk about "deployment". Your pipelines should have at least 1 deployment keyword in the pipe. So i have attach some examples pipelines. But great to see your found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples to run python with bitbucket pipelines.
You can change unit test according to yours.

1. First make sure pipelines are enabled.
2. Generate SSH.
3. Add host key.
4. Add variable to Deployment menu.

I'm also attach running pipelines with tags and branch.

Generate SSH from :

```
https://bitbucket.org/<WORKSPACE>/<REPOSITORY_NAME>/admin/addon/admin/pipelines/ssh-keys
```

and put it to your server `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

```
definitions: 
  
  steps:
  
    # Build
    - step: &build
        name: Install and Test
        image: python:3.7.2
        trigger: automatic
        script:
          - pip install -r requirements.txt
          - python3 test.py test

     # Deployment
     - step: &deploy
        name: Deploy Artifacts
        trigger: automatic
        deployment: test
        script:

          # Deploy New Artifact
          - pipe: atlassian/scp-deploy:0.3.11
            variables:
              USER: <REMOTE_USER>
              SERVER: <REMOTE_HOST>
              REMOTE_PATH: <REMOTE_PATH>
              LOCAL_PATH: $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/**


# Runner
pipelines:

  # Running by tags
  tags:
    v*:
      - step: *build
      - step: 
          <<: *deploy
          deployment: test
          trigger: manual

  # Running by branch
  branches:

    master:
      - step: *build
      - step:
          <<: *deploy
          deployment: test
          trigger: automatic
```